# Undefined local variable Error when running ruby script in Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, jenkins

So I have created a ruby on rails application that functions as a basic calculator. I would like to run some ruby unit tests on it in Jenkins. To do so I did the following steps in order:

- I created a new free style job
- loaded the app from my repo
- made sure to check the option to "Run the build in a RVM-managed environment"
- inputted my Ruby version number (2.3.1)
- added a build step to execute ruby script
- tried to run my app with the following commands: "cd (directory with unit tests), ruby (unit test file)"

But when I do so I get the following error: undefined local variable or method `(unit test file)'. When I test the same commands on my console they work perfectly.

Did I miss a configuration step? Would some be able to provide me with a list of their configurations that they used? Has anyone else gotten this error? How did you solve it?

Would someone be able to provide me with a good tutorial link for setting up and running a Jenkins job to execute ruby unit tests? I have tried the [following tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+a+Rails+build), but I got lost at the very end. Is there a better tutorial that you have used?

Comment: Where is this error happening? Would you mind to post your code? Our divinatory capabilities are offline for a while.

Comment: Capturing environment variables produced by 'rvm use 2.3.1'
$ bash -c export
$ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[ruby_pipeline] $ bash -c " source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create 2.3.1 && export > rvm.env"
Using /home/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
[ruby_pipeline] $ ruby -v /tmp/hudson3068961272993514100.rb
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
/tmp/hudson3068961272993514100.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `test_calc.rb' for main:Object (NameError)